# How to stop echoing gallery inside content?

Tags: filters, gallery

I want to completely stop echoing gallery inside `the_content()` because I am showing it in different position outside content as per design (with a help of `get_post_gallery_images()`). It is a custom theme from scratch, there are almost no plugins yet installed, I have tried it with this, but it does nothing.

```
 add_filter('post_gallery', '__return_false', 999);
```

This only works partially, if I return empty string it still shows gallery, but if I return some string it shows that instead.

```
add_filter('post_gallery', 'test', 999999);
function test() {
    return ''; // Shows gallery
    return 'asdfasdf'; // Doesn't show gallery but outputs this string
}
```

Comment: So why don't you return `<!-- Here be dragons. -->` instead?

Comment: @IvanTopić Note the none-strict comparison in `$output = apply_filters( 'post_gallery', '', $attr, $instance ); if ( $output != '' ) { return $output; }`, so `false != ''` is false, that's why your `__return_false` will not work but the suggestion from @fuxia will work..

Comment: Thank you it works. I didn't even thought about returning a comment, nice hack

Comment: Actually, I just noticed... This also removes the gallery I want to show in different place, because now get_post_gallery_images() doesn't return anything -.-